# Angular + Firebase Cloud Messaging: Requests to this API fcmregistrations.googleapis.com are blocked

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Angular 13 Application using firebase (v 9.7.0) & the [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) (v 7.2) package.

I did the [tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/messaging/messaging.md) from @angular/fire and i get the following error message when trying to create a fcm token in my firebase app:

[image]

I added the gcm_sender_id to my manifest file & my firebase-messaging-sw.js looks like this:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.5/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.5/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '*****',
    authDomain: '*****',
    projectId: '*****',
    storageBucket: '*****',
    messagingSenderId: '*****',
    appId: '*****',
    measurementId: '*****',
 });

 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

this is how I try to obtain the token:
[image]

I also checked all required APIs in the google cloud console, all are activated and running.

What can I do to not block the registration request?

Answer (score 0):

The browser should have blocked the notifications.
If you are using google chrome then click on the info icon on the left side of the address and enable notifications